# Android xml and gradle code changed suddenly and shows Auto generated code

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle

Suddenly my code in xml changed to some auto-generated code and shows another project's name

[image]

This above code is my original xml code. And it has turned into below auto-generated code.

[image]

It'll be very helpful if someone can provide any kind of help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Reinstall the Android Studio **without** importing the old config will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has occurred when I migrate to android studio 3.2.1

For me, it works after deleting android cache folder.
You can delete this folder from this location.

C:\Users\user_name\.gradle\caches

Note: Close the android studio before you delete this folder.

Comment: Okay.
Only one option left.
Please reinstall android studio.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Solved my problem by copy paste previous codes into these files. Took hours do that. But didn't find any other solution.